# Oracle Table-valued Functions returns erroneous decimals in Data Factory

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-functions, azure-data-factory

I am working on a cloud datawarehouse using Azure Data Factory v2.
Quite a few of my data sources are on-prem Oracle 12g databases.
Extracting tables 1-1 is not a problem.
However, from time to time I need to extract data generated by parametrized computations on the fly in my Copy Activities.

Since I cannot use PL/SQL stored procedures as sources in ADF, I instead use table-valued functions in the source database and query them in the copy activity.

In the majority of the cases, this works fine. However, when my table-valued function returns a decimal type column, ADF sometimes returns erroneous values. That is: executing the TVF on the source db and previeweing/copying through ADF yields different results.

I have done some experiments if the absolute value or the sign of the decimal number matters, but I cannot find any pattern in which decimals are returned correctly and which are not.

Here are a few examples of the erroneously mapped numbers:

| Value in Oracle db | Value in ADF |
| --- | --- |
| -658388.5681 | 188344991.6319 |
| -205668.1648 | 58835420.6352 |
| 10255676.84 | 188213627.97348 |

1. Has any of you experienced similar problems?
2. Do you know if this is a bug in ADF (which is not integrating well to PL/SQL in the first place)?

**First hypothesis**

At first I thought the issue was related to NLS, casting or something similar.
I tested this hypothesis by creating a table on the Oracle db side, persisted the output form the TVF there and then extracted from the table in ADF.
Using this method, the decimals were returned correctly in ADF. Thus the hypothesis does not hold.

**Second hypothesis**

It might have to do with user accesses.
However the linked service used in ADF uses the same db credentials as the ones used to log in to the database to execute the TVF there.

**Observation**

The error seems to happen more often when a lot of aggregate functions are involved in the tvf's logic

**Minimum reproducible example**

Oracle db:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_col AS OBJECT
(
dec_col NUMBER(20,5)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE test_tbl AS TABLE OF test_col;

create or replace function test_fct(param date) return test_tbl
AS
ret_tbl test_tbl;
begin
select
    test_col(
    <"some complex logic which return a decimal">
    )
 bulk collect into ret_tbl
 from <"some complex joins and group by's">;
 
 return ret_tbl;
end test_fct;

select dec_col from table(test_fct(sysdate));
```

ADF:
Dataset:

```
{
    "name": "test_dataset",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "some_name",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "some_name"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "OracleTable",
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "dec_col",
                "type": "Decimal"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Pipeline:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "OracleSource",
                        "oracleReaderQuery": "select * from table(test_fct(sysdate))",
                        "partitionOption": "None",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00"
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "test_dataset",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Do your complex logic or joins have any implicit conversions, from or to numbers or dates? Different NLS session parameters seem likely a likely candidate, but without seeing the raw data and how it's being manipulated it's hard to tell.

Comment: @AlexPoole , the logic involves calling other functions, passing dates back and forth etc. However the ADF will always pass any date parameter as strings of either form `sysdate` or `TO_DATE('20201231','YYYYMMDD')` to avoid problems with implicit conversions.

I know it's hard to tell, without seeing the actual data and logic. However it is hard to reveal either of those in a meaningful way without granting rights to my companies production Oracle db ;)

Comment: I saw that sysdate was being passed in, so I was only asking about the logic in the function. And I understand you're restricted; but if the problem is in that code you can't show us then we can't really help. You can maybe try to see if it's from conversions, possibly in other functions,  by calling your function directly with different session NLS settings and see if that changes the results. I'd start by changing NLS_DATE_FORMAT to have 2 or 4 digit years - which seems a likely culprit - and then change other things.

Comment: Thanks @AlexPoole . I'm sorry I cannot provide more details. But I will try playing around with the NLS_DATE_FORMAT on session level and see if there are any implicit conversions that could affect the result. I will let you know if that solves the problem.

Comment: I have no idea what Azure is. With that said: if "computations" result in such differences in results, I would suspect the data types, and how "errors" (such as numeric overflow) are handled. Oracle supports integers up to 32 digits. If you "talk" to a system that only supports integers up to 64 binary digits, for example, that's only about 20 decimal digits. Perhaps if you try to transmit a value that's too large directly, that will fail; but in computations, an engine may wrap on numeric overflow - in the end resulting in a wrong output from the computation. I'd look into that first.